# How many forms of kryptonite are there?

Tags: dc, superman

I was watching an episode of Smallville the other day and they had a different form of kryptonite which instead of hurting Superman removed his inhibitions. It was red, different from the original green I'm used to seeing.

Is this something they made up for the show or are there really different versions of kryptonite in the comics. If so, how many? And how do they affect Superman?

Comment: This kind of perfectly fits the definition of "general reference". The first search result is the wikipedia page linked in the answer below.

Comment: @Beofett I've tried to summarize the information from wikipedia.

Comment: Also of relevance; ["Are there any comics where Superman is influenced by several types of Kryptonite in the same time?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71511/are-there-any-comics-where-superman-is-influenced-by-several-types-of-kryptonite).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Pre/Post-Crisis

Here is quick summary the various types found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite) with corrections from [dc.wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite):

- **Green*** -  Exposure to green kryptonite radiation will greatly weaken a Kryptonian, robbing them of their powers. Prolonged exposure to green kryptonite proves fatal. Once appears by mistake as Purple.
- **Red***  - A variety of effects, *Pre-Crisis*: from hallucination, changing form, paralysis and, when combined with green kryptonite radiation, even the growing of a third eye at the back of Superman's head. *Post-Crisis*:  intense pain as well as his powers to behave oddly and his skin to become transparent. In *Other media*: Amnesia, Apathy, loss of inhibitions.
- **Gold*** - Pre-Crisis, it permanently removes superpowers from Kryptonians. Possibly removed Post-Crisis. Effects are temporary post-crisis
- **Blue** - Blue kryptonite is the Bizarro analogue to green kryptonite. It has had healing effects on Superman. In *Smallville* it suppresses Kryptonians' powers and removes their sensitivity to green kryptonite. It can also purify water.
- **Black** - First appeared in *Smallville*. Split the personality of Kryptonians. Later appears in *Supergirl* with the same effect.
- **White** - Kills all plant life, whether Kryptonian or not. In *Superman III* causes Mr S to become irritable.
- **Silver** - *Smallville*: Paranoid delusions. *Batman/Superman*: A piece of silver kryptonite causes Superman to act like a hyperactive child. *Post Crisis*: 'For Kryptonians, exposure to silver kryptonite yields effects similar to that of Cannabis on a human being'.
- **Orange** - Gives animals super powers.
- **Jewel/Gemstone** - Jewel kryptonite amplifies the psychic powers of Phantom Zone residents. In *Smallville* cause others to want to fulfil your wishes.
- **Anti-** - Has the effect of green kryptonite on non-superpowered kryptonians.
- **X-** -  Can imbue Earth-based life-forms with temporary superpowers. May act like the Green variety.
- **Slow** - Green Kryptonite for humans.
- **Magno-** - Supermagnetic to items from krypton.
- **Bizarro Red** - Red Kryptonite for humans.
- **-X/Kryptisium** - Restores kryptonians powers after they are drained.
- **Pink** - Imparts homosexual tendencies on Superman.
- **Hybrid-** - Green Kryptonite for humans.

Items marked with a star are present post-crisis.

### The New 52

In the *New 52* things have changed for kryptonite:

- **Green**: It weakens a kryptonian and can kill him if he's exposed to either extreme levels or a long period of time. Although it doesn't incapacitates Superman as it did in previous timelines, it can still be used to weaken or kill him.
- **Red**: Now in its raw form or even energized only causes hallucinations both to kryptonians and humans.
- **Blue**: Kills the spirit of a kryptonian.
- There was also mentioned, **Silver**, **Platinum**, and **Black** kryptonite, although their effects are still unknown at the time.

Comment: So the answer is 17?