# What kinds of Kryptonite are still in circulation?

Tags: dc, comics, kryptonite

In researching [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13874/3804) question I came upon a problem. *Multiple* places said that only Green existed post-crisis (*current version of the DC universe?), but others stated other types. I could not pin down which forms of kryptonite are still extant. That is to say haven't been thrown into the sun, retconned or removed form the comics in some other way.

I couldn't find an authoritative answer elsewhere on the web, so I've come here.

Comment: Isn't that what the * marked variants in your answer were?

Comment: Multiple continuities is going to be a problem here.  Do you mean in the mainstream comics continuity, in the Diniverse, in the movies?  Even just in comics, the New 52 continuity shift makes all of our assumptions pretty much meaningless.  A number of forms of Kryptonite were shown in Action Comics 5-6, I believe, and that's the best reference I can think of.

Comment: @Xantec Yes but I couldn't be sure. *Multiple* places said that only Green existed post-crisis (*current version of the DC universe?), but others stated other types. I couldn't find an authoritative answer, so I've come here.

Comment: @RedArrogantKnight In the mainstream.

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but the Kryptonite shown in Action Comics is all I've got.  It shows that a lot of the colorful Kryptonite forms are still in-continuity, even post-Flashpoint.  That was a Morrison story, so it involved time travel and I have no idea when they'd be considered 'in circulation'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the New Earth, DCnU, there has only been three forms of kryptonite. The naturally occurring green variety and an artificially produced red and gold variants. Since the creation of New Earth, no other variants have been seen, yet.

- Red caused Superman's powers to become uncontrollable.
- Gold caused Superman to temporarily lose his powers.

From the [DC Wikia Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite):

> In the Post-Crisis primary New Earth universe, there is only one
>   natural form of Kryptonite, Green. All others forms of Kryptonite in
>   the New Earth dimension are artifically created from Green through
>   certain techniques to produce these other forms, such as radiation
>   bombardment to accelerate Green's half-cycle into Red. Luthor has
>   successfully recreated Gold in the New Earth dimension, which strips
>   all power processing of Kryptonians' bodies, though seemingly it is
>   only temporary in its effect and not permanent unlike the Pre-Crisis
>   Earth-One Gold Kryptonite. (Action Comics Annual #11 (2008))

Comment: Is there any change to the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Since the debut of [The New 52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52)'s "Prime-Earth", the post-[Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_%28comics%29) DC Universe continuity, only Green Kryptonite has appeared.

One caveat here is that The New 52 has undergone a partial-reboot in the form of 2015's [Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_%28comics%29). While leaving most or all of Prime-Earth's history intact, Convergence has introduced parts of some previously-rebooted DC continuities to Prime-Earth. One of these is the [Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Superman_comics#Superman:_Lois_and_Clark) from New Earth, the pre-Flashpoint DC continuity. So, while Green Kryptonite is the only form to appear within the new continuity, a character from an old continuity who has encountered the alternate forms of Kryptonite detailed in Thaddeus's answer is now an active, if isolated, part of Prime-Earth.