# Could Superman be killed by a bullet made out of Kryptonite?

Tags: dc, superman

Superman's only weaknesses are magic and Kryptonite (the latter makes him lose his durability).

If he was shot using a bullet made out of Kryptonite, would it kill him?

Comment: There are more weaknesses: Radiation of red sun etc.

Comment: Poor question. Kryptonite radiation exposure is enough to kill Superman. Why would anyone need Kryptonite bullet?

Comment: You should ask Batman.

Comment: @b_jonas will do :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Smallville Wikia](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite_bullet):

> A green kryptonite bullet can neutralize both a Kryptonian's invulnerability and their healing factor. This makes bullets a potent weapon against Kryptonians; if a green kryptonite bullet is not removed soon after a Kryptonian is shot, it can potentially kill him or her.

And on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite#Variations):

> In Lois and Clark, a green Kryptonite bullet is also used to bring Superman back in control when his powers become over-amped by red Kryptonite and a sample of Kryptonite was used to starve out a Kryptonian virus Superman was introduced to by Mrs. Church.

And [again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite#Justice_League:_Doom):

> Green Kryptonite appears in the direct to video movie, Justice League: Doom. In the film, Metallo nearly kills Superman by shooting him the chest with a bullet made of Green Kryptonite, sending him falling from the roof of the Daily Planet and onto the pavement below. Superman's Kryptonian skin prevents the paramedics at the scene from removing the bullet, but he is ultimately saved after Cyborg uses a makeshift Kryptonite laser to cut an incision in the hero's chest, allowing Martian Manhunter to remove the Kryptonite before it kills him.

I'm sure there are other instances of kryptonite bullets, but mostly it's just a handy way of getting the krpytonite to him. Frankly though, superman is unlikely to be killed off so we won't see a kryptonite bullet used successfully on him.

The fact it's in bullet form has nothing, or at least very little to do with the delivery method. [Other types of kryptonite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13874/3804) would behave the same. I think only green has been made into bullets.

Comment: There're many forms of Kryptonite which don't harm Superman at all. I wish you include that..

Comment: @SachinShekhar My wish is your command.

Comment: Another smallville reference: http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite_bullet The topic was explored in four different episodes.

Comment: @ForceFlow that's my first link...? Is there something I missed?

Comment: +1 Pureferret, does Sachin get three wishes? and afterwords can I get three?

Comment: @NominSim Oh no. You misread: '**My** wish is **your** command' ;)

Comment: @Pureferret Must have holistic dyslexia...well now I suppose I owe *you* wishes...

Comment: @Pureferret hm, I could've sworn your link was a link to one of the episodes. Oh well.

Comment: I bet a mini gun full of green kryptonite bullets can take out Superman :P