# Are there any comics where Superman is influenced by several types of Kryptonite in the same time?

Tags: dc, superman

I've seen and know some types of Kryptonite and know what its effects are, but is there something canon (or even non-canon) that shows what effects can happen when various **different types** of Kryptonite influence Superman at the same time?

Comment: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090603171617/superman/images/8/87/Kryptonite_Varietals.jpg - An overview

Comment: And some indications of what happens when they're mixed; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite#Forms_of_Kryptonite

Comment: I also imagine that whatever effect that such an amalgam would have would be influenced by whatever the effect of the Red K would be were he exposed to it by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, there are several times when Superman is exposed to multiple kinds of Kryptonite:**

*Red and Green Kryptonite dust* seems to rob him of his powers permanently ([Superman #152](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superboy_Vol_1_121))

[image]

A ray comprising Red and Green Kryptonite causes him to develop a third eye in [Action Comics #275](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_275)

[image]

Red and Gold Kryptonite gives Superman 'super-amnesia' in [Superman #178](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_178)

[image]

---

There are also two "*imaginary stories*" involving mixed kryptonite sources.

In [Superman #192](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_192), Superman is subjected to an alloy of Gold, Red and Green Kryptonite. The effects are that he has amnesia ***and*** loses his powers.

[image]

In [Superman #162](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_162), Superman exposes himself to the rays of Red, Gold, Green and Blue Kyrptonite. The effect is to literally split himself into two identical (and hyper intelligent) Supermen.

[image]