# Have we ever seen a Kryptonian simultaneously affected by more than one variety of Kryptonite?

Tags: dc, superman

I'm working on a fan theory, and I'm curious if in any iteration of various Kryptonians we have seen one affected by, say, red and green kryptonite at the same time. This doesn't have to be any particular canon, where tv, movies, cartoons, comics, serials.super

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71553/20774

Comment: I always assume that people tried to find thread about their question and failed so I answer it :D XD

Comment: I am sure I recall statements in Silver Age comics that said if a Kryptonian is under the influence of red kryptonite then they can't be affected by the other versions.

Comment: In my defense, I did look but didn't find anything. Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite)

Red-Green: first variety: Debuted in Action Comics #275 (April 1961). An alloy created by the villainous character Brainiac, it caused Superman to mutate, temporarily growing a third eye in the back of his head.

Red-Green : second variety: Debuted in Superboy Comics #121 (June 1965). Causes Superboy to lose his powers permanently but Phantom Zone criminal Vakox unwillingly cures him, restoring his powers.

Red-Green-Blue-Gold : Debuted in Superman #162 (July 1963). An imaginary story in which Superman combines the minerals to power a device to boost his intelligence. An explosion causes a mishap and the character is split into two separate beings ("Superman-Blue" and "Superman-Red"), both of whom possess enhanced intelligence.

Red-Gold: Debuted in Superman #178 (July 1965). Temporarily deprives Kryptonians of their memories.

Red-Green-Gold: Debuted in Superman #192 (Jan. 1967). An imaginary story in which the alloy permanently removes the character's abilities and memories of ever having been Superman.